# .lower() for x in list, not working, but works in another scenario

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

The below gives me: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'.

I want to convert each item in the list I created from the passed in arguments to lower case.

I convert tuple to list , as to my understanding tuples cannot be changed
then when I try to lowercase I get the error.

```
def is_purple(*lfp):
    lower1 = [i for i in lfp]
    empty_string = [x.lower() for x in lower1]
    return empty_string


print(is_purple(1,2,"colors","Purple"))
```

But, If I do this:

```
print([x.lower() for x in ["A","B","C"]])
```

It works. I hit the search and typed

.lower() not working, and I am too stupid to see what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Exception is self-explaining:  `'int' object has no attribute 'lower'.`  - you try to call `something.lower()` but `something` is of type `int`  and has no `lower()`...

Comment: As an aside, this line: `lower1 = [i for i in lfp]` is totally unnecessary, and furthermore, it is an overly verbose way of writing `lower1 = list(lfp)`

Answer (score 2):

Because, you have non-strings in your list. Only strings have `.lower()` function. So before you do `.lower()`, check if it's a string:

```
def is_purple(*lfp):
    empty_string = [x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lfp]
    return empty_string

print(is_purple(1,2,"colors","Purple"))
# [1, 2, 'colors', 'purple']
```

`isinstance(x, str)` checks if `x` is string. We do `.lower()` if this returns a `True` else retain the list item as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing multiple values into `is_purple` two of type `int` and two of type `string`. `lower()` is a function which can only be called on strings, and will therefore throw an error when you try to call it on an `int`

In your second example you're only calling `.lower()` on objects which are a `string` and therefore it does work.

Answer (score 0):

`@Travis`, you can try this:

```
>>> def is_purple(*lfp): return [i.lower() if type(i) is str else i for i in lfp]
...
>>> print(is_purple(1,2,"colors","Purple"))
[1, 2, 'colors', 'purple']
>>>
```

> So you can change your code as shown below (if you wish) to make it working.

```
>>> def is_purple(*lfp):
...     lower1 = [i for i in lfp]
...     empty_string = [x.lower() if type(x) is str else x for x in lower1]
...     return empty_string
...
>>> print(is_purple(1,2,"colors","Purple"))
[1, 2, 'colors', 'purple']
>>>
```

Comment: `@juanpa`, you are correct, I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

your issue stem from the fact that you give `is_purple` a list of ints and strings.  To be more precise, (int, int, string, string) in your example.

Here we can see that `1` is of type `int` and that `"Purple"` is of type string which is not a problem for Python since you can mix-and-match types in a list.

```
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
>>> type("Purple")
<class 'str'>
```

To fix your issue you can either assuming that your intend was to use all strings as illustrated with your second example:

call `print(is_purple(str(1),str(2),"colors","Purple"))`

Or explcitly cast your inputs as `str` (Note the `str(i)`)

```
def is_purple(*lfp):
    lower1 = [str(i) for i in lfp]
    empty_string = [x.lower() for x in lower1]
    return empty_string
```

Or, if you want a more compact version

```
def is_purple(*lfp): 
   return [str(i).lower() for i in lfp]
```

But, the best solution if your `lfp` input can be extremely large, would be best to do a generator, an advanced technique that is lighter and more efficient with memory.

```
def is_purple_gen(*lfp): 
   for i in lfp: 
      yield str(i).lower()

print(list(is_purple_gen(1,2,"colors","Purple"))  )                                                                                                                  
['1', '2', 'colors', 'purple']
```

Note that with the generator, I had to add list() but in a situation where `lfp` could be big and processed one entry at a time, generators are the best choice.

Comment: Alternative to `str(i).lower` in Python 3.6+: `f'{i}'.lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use first two arguments then just define and never use them like this here `a=1` and `b=2` and `lfp` contains all other arguments which I assume are of `str` so you do not need to check if they are of str type and can be used directly.

```
def is_purple(a,b,*lfp):
    lower1 = [i for i in lfp]
    empty_string = [x.lower() for x in lower1]
    return empty_string


print(is_purple(1,2,"colors","Purple"))
```

Also you can remove the intermediate list and reduce the code

```
def is_purple(a,b,*lfp):
    empty_string = [x.lower() for x in lfp]
    return empty_string

print(is_purple(1,2,"colors","Purple"))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_purple(*lfp):
...     lower1 = [i for i in lfp]
...     empty_string = [x.lower() if type(x) is str else x for x in lower1]
...     return empty_string
 ...
print(is_purple(1,2,"colors","Purple"))
[1, 2, 'colors', 'purple']
```

Comment: Add a little elaboration. ;)

Comment: other users cant understand code only answers. little bit explanation really helps others. : Review